# Is it possible to use safari cookie in Application web view

Tags: ios, xamarin, safari, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I just want to know if you think it's possible to get credentials from safari cookie to log someone directly in web view in my app.
I have a "linkedin connect" way to connect into my app.
For the moment, if you have the Linkedin application installed on your device, you could connect in one click. But if you don't have it locally, I opened a webview on linkedin to ask you if you are ok to give us access to your information to create your profile. But currently the user has to re-enter their email and password manually since they don't benefit from the browser's login data. 
I would like to fill the field or connect directly the user if he was connected in safari, Do you think it's possible, if yes, what can I used to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**, thats not possible. Safari is different app  than your app and hence web view is safari don't share anything with web view with your app until it has extension to share.bjects of UIWebView class and Safari or other browsers are different  and  sandboxed. You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage)  (official documentation.)

What you want with Linked in is possible with Facebook -- because face book login authentication method provides way to share data between apps --  But in Linkedin  there is no similar way.

Answer (score 2):

As given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192778/how-to-share-cookies-from-my-ios-app-to-mobile-safari), Safari and UIWebview don't seem to share cookies as they are sand boxed from one another.